# Which httpmime version can I use with Android's HttpClient?

Tags: android, file-upload, androidhttpclient

I need to upload files using Android's HttpClient. Unfortunately, [Android doesn't include MultipartEntity](http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/), so I must using [Apache's httpmime library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/project-info.html).

I don't want to incur possible conflicts between the Android's HttpClient and the official HttpClient. Also, I don't want to bring in more outside libraries than I have to because I need to keep my method count low.

What version of httpmime will work with Android's HttpClient? [All of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19266918/9636) I've seen [recommending httpmime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220954/9636) also recommend [using Apache's official HttpClient or HttpCore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2937140/9636).

(I know I should use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), but I must use Android's HttpClient for compatibility with other libraries.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`httpmime-4.2.6.jar`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpmime%7C4.2.6%7Cjar) worked fine all by itself. I needed no other dependencies besides that jar.

If you're using a dependency-managing build system like `Maven` or `gradle`, you'll notice that [`httpmime-4.2.6` depends on `httpcore-4.2.5`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.6/). Android's HttpClient seems compatible with `httpcore-4.2.5`, so I just excluded that dependency. My actual dependency declaration is below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
}
```

Comment: though `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'`might look nicer.