# Error:Execution failed for task in android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

when i try to add the jar files to my project i got the error like **Error:Execution** failed for task

> ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/apache/http/annotation/Immutable.class in android studio

build.gradle

```
ultConfig {
        applicationId "com.syzygy.extreme.uploadexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: `duplicate entry` same library calling one more time

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.jar')
}

Comment: comment this line `compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')`

Comment: then `Clean-Rebuild-Run` .Let me inform .

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/annotation/Immutable.class

Comment: @krishnaveni, check my answer.. it is 100% working

Comment: @krishnaveni call `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'` instead of your 3 library .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761347/which-httpmime-version-can-i-use-with-androids-httpclient

Comment: Error:(9, 30) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(10, 38) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(11, 35) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(47, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(47, 45) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(48, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(48, 41) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost

Comment: please resolve my problem..iam not able to use the http client and request

Comment: @ krishnaveni, have u used my code(dependencies) ?

Comment: yeap..i have used..i got the warning like  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy while build the project

Comment: @krishnaveni add `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'`

Answer (score -1):

Try this out for http core and mime. 100% working

```
android {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abcd"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
```

Comment: hi @NikPatel your reply is useful to me can u please mention that how to change version '4.3.5.1' i am try to use update library for that i am try to update client library version like '4.5.1' but it will not excepted.Thank you