# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: java, android

Please need your help...

this my app build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wiimii"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[When i press on "build apk" i get this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaDhu.png)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/annotation/Immutable.class

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912925/errorexecution-failed-for-task-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

```
**Finally this the way I fix the problem:**
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wiimii"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//this I adding to fix the http... jar file
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
//necessary  
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
//also need this for deal with com.android.support.test
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
//add this jar file manually to libs directory  
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```